# ng-annotate error with Babel and destructuring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, babeljs, destructuring, ng-annotate

Strange error when transpiling to ES6 with Babel, `ng-annotate` doesn't like destructuring.  I copied my source into the online babel compiler and it works fine. Commenting out `ng-annotate` in my gulp pipe chain gets rid of the error.  Removing the `/* @ngAnnotate */` comment in the file and injecting manually doesn't change anything either.

Gulp section:

```
return gulp.src(config.scripts.app)
    .pipe(changed(config.dist + '/scripts'))
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(annotate())

    // Filter out and transpile only .es6.js files
    .pipe(es6)
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['es2015'],
        plugins: ['extensible-destructuring'],
        comments: false
    }))
    .pipe(es6.restore)

    .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + '/scripts'))
```

Source in question:

```
var [min, max] = values.map(val => +val);
// let/var doesn't make a difference.

ngModelCtrl.$modelValue = [min, max];
```

Error is coming from a dependency in `ng-annotate`:

```
Error: StringMap expected string key
    at stringmap.set (/Users/macbookair/Places/app/places/frontend/node_modules/gulp-ng-annotate/node_modules/ng-annotate/node_modules/stringmap/stringmap.js:101:19)
    at Scope.add (/Users/macbookair/Places/app/places/frontend/node_modules/gulp-ng-annotate/node_modules/ng-annotate/build/es5/scope.js:102:17)
    at /Users/macbookair/Places/app/places/frontend/node_modules/gulp-ng-annotate/node_modules/ng-annotate/build/es5/scopetools.js:38:25
    at Array.forEach (native)
    .... more
```

`stringmap.js` function in question:

```
stringmap.prototype.set = function(key, value) {    
    if (typeof key !== "string") {
        throw new Error("StringMap expected string key");
    }
    if (key === "__proto__") {
        this.hasProto = true;
        this.proto = value;
    } else {
        this.obj[key] = value;
    }
};
```

Logging out `key` and `value` in the above function returns this:

```
undefined { 
    kind: 'var', 
    node: { 
        type: 'ArrayPattern',
        start: 1178,
        end: 1188,
        loc: { start: [Object], end: [Object] },
        range: [ 1178, 1188 ],
        elements: [ [Object], [Object] ] 
    },
    from: 1215 
}
```

Clearly the `key` argument is undefined, but why does it even care?

Comment: I have similar problem, I just simply changed the order in gulp pipe to: babel --> annotate. ng-annotate does not support new JS versions: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate/issues/237.

Comment: Thanks @illagrenan, yep after some trial and error (keep comments etc) I ended up just piping .es6.js files to babel and skipping implicit ng-annotate.  I'm growing to like the explicit annotations anyway :) Someday get all files to es2015 regardless.

Comment: @illagrenan changing the order of tasks worked for me too :) Thanks

Comment: We were having issues ng Annotate plugin and switched to babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate and fixes the problem. But we are using this plugin with webpack

Comment: @illagrenan could you put that into answer? it could be tricky to find out solution that works through comments :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have similar problem, I just simply changed the order in gulp pipe to: 
>   babel --> annotate. ng-annotate does not support new JS versions: [github.com/olov/ng-annotate/issues/237](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate/issues/237)

Originally answered by @illagrenan in comment section above